# terraform backend s3 bucket creation returns 403 w/ Terraform 0.11.1

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform

How do I create an S3 bucket that has access to put a terraform.tfstate file? How do I get the tfstate into the bucket? What is the proper way to do this?

To preface, I have spent over 6 hours trying to figure this out. I saw the [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47669894/terraform-s3-bucket-creation-causes-not-authorized) with a problem caused by MFA. That's not my issue.

I'm using the same code to create EC2 instances, VPC and other resources just fine.

```
---[ REQUEST POST-SIGN ]-----------------------------
GET /?prefix=env%3A%2F HTTP/1.1
Host: tfstate-neonaluminum.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
User-Agent: aws-sdk-go/1.10.36 (go1.9.2; darwin; amd64) APN/1.0 HashiCorp/1.0 Terraform/0.11.1
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=<CUT>/20171215/us-east-2/s3/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date, Signature=<CUT>
X-Amz-Content-Sha256: <CUT>
X-Amz-Date: 20171215T103755Z
Accept-Encoding: gzip

-----------------------------------------------------
2017/12/15 04:37:55 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Response s3/ListObjects Details:
---[ RESPONSE ]--------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Connection: close
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Fri, 15 Dec 2017 10:37:55 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
X-Amz-Bucket-Region: us-east-2
X-Amz-Id-2: UwWJlCAtabKny2Ncam+D7/s9Rozjw43ozsVNdtZgQqPSXoSvZbO3JnuPz3B9cmLcgYea6x8xPqQ=
X-Amz-Request-Id: 470C02B96A60090B
```

Here's the .tf code:

```
provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
    region  = "${var.region}"
}

terraform {
   backend "s3" {
    bucket = "tfstate-neonaluminum"
       key = "terraform.tfstate"
    region = "us-east-2"
  }
}
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "terraform_state_bucket" {
  bucket = "tfstate-neonaluminum"
  acl = "private"
  tags {
    management = "terraform"
  }
}
```

Hope I didn't leave out any necessary details - new to asking questions on stackoverflow.

Comment: Does your provided key (`var.aws_access_key`) have write and list privileges to the s3 bucket `tfstate-neonaluminum`?

Comment: Is it actually possibly to use s3 as your backend with the bucket also being created by Terraform? I'm not sure either way but I would have expected the bucket is required to exist before Terraform can run, otherwise how will it pull in the state files?

Comment: Yes, I created the S3 bucket with terraform already. I assume I can use the same keys I created the bucket with to also write to the bucket?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately that's the one caveat for using S3 as your backend to Terraform; you'll need to create the bucket manually. At times - a common pattern is that an organization will have multiple AWS accounts (For a variety of reasons - not just Terraform state) - this could be a possible option, to throw create your S3 bucket in that account, that way you can keep **all** of your other account's infrastructure defined by Terraform - but personally, I just create it by hand in my own account.

One thing you can do, is import the bucket after the fact with `terraform import` if you wanted to manage it with Terraform, just of course there's the chicken and the egg problem still. Or - use a local state initially while creating the bucket, and then define it later; however either way you would not be able to dynamically reference the bucket via the resource object.

But no - you cannot simultaneously create the bucket with Terraform while also setting it to your state.

Comment: This makes sense. I actually have created a local state file and want to change the tf script to use a remote state file.

Comment: My S3 bucket is created remotely. Can I just drop the tf state file in S3 via the console?

Comment: @Neal Just change it from local to remote and run an apply - Terraform will do it for you

Comment: It's not really that difficult.  You can have 1 terraform module w/ a local backend to create all of the state buckets for all of your accounts.  Then the rest of the modules use the previously-created state bucket as normal.  There is absolutely no need to do it manually